# How to avoid getting imaginary/complex number python

Tags: python, complex-numbers, cmath

I am using a python code, where one of the equations got sqrt root of negative value. I use `cmath.sqrt` to solve it. All answers I got from that equation are shown in imaginary/complex number (e.g. x.xxxxx**j**). I don't want to get that imaginary/complex number as the code that I use subsequently cannot read those imaginary/ complex number. As such, how can I avoid not to get imaginary numbers? OR in other way, how can I convert those imaginary number into real ones? or how can I remove those "j". Thanks.

Comment: I hope you're not asking how to get a real number when you take the square root of a negative number, because that's impossible.

Comment: If you don't calculate the root of negative numbers you won't get imaginary numbers.

Comment: when I calculate sqrt root of neg value with matlab or perl, I got the imaginary number but they are not shown with "j" , i think. Sorry for my ignorance if I make mistake. As my subsequent can't proceed if the number has "j"

Comment: @meemee: How do you want them to be shown?

Comment: Just without "j". e.g. 5.88410474075 instead of 5.88410474075+0j. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question you either want

```
abs(z)
```

or

```
z.real
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop the imaginary part from the value which you got after square root of any random number in python, so you can simply do:

```py
value = sqrt(any number)

# for only real part
value = value.real
```