# root of negative number

Tags: math, python-3.6

doing wrong account while getting python root

```py
>>>(-27)**(1/3) #must be -3
>>>(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)
```

do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know how to make it return -3, but 1.5 + 2.59i s also a cube root of -27. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37246418/how-to-avoid-getting-imaginary-complex-number-python) might help?

Comment: Above comment and the answer, both are correct but assume that you are aware of the concept of complex numbers. Are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct answer for the usual branch cut for [`log`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.log).

If you start from 27 and go to -27 along the circle `|z|=27` in the complex plane, then the cubic root will go from 3 to 1.5+2.6i if you follow the upper half-plane and to 1.5-2.6i if you follow the lower one.

**PS**. If you are unfamiliar with [branch cuts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/245579/37092), you can start with [pretty pictures](https://flothesof.github.io/branch-cuts-with-square-roots.html).
If you unfamiliar with [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), start with [fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/complex-numbers.html).

Comment: very Thanks man!